# Converting AMF Number from char to double an back

Tags: c, amf

in context of a protokoll I get messages in [AMF](https://rtmp.veriskope.com/pdf/amf0-file-format-specification.pdf) Format.

The AMF Object Type "Number" is defined as

> number-type = number-marker DOUBLE

> The data following a Number type marker is always an 8 byte IEEE-754 double [...] in network byte order.

The following Examples are captured using Wireshark:

Hex: 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Number: 2

Hex: 40 08 00 00 00 00 00 00
Number: 3

Hex: 3f f0 00 00 00 00 00 00
Number: 1

I tried to treat these as doube, long long and int64_t but none of these Types seems to use the correct order/format.

The implementation needs to be in C so I cant use any Librarys (The are none as it seems)

What would be the correct approach?

Comment: Your captures cannot be right because a "number-marker" is always a single 0x00 byte and an 8 byte IEEE-754 double is always 8 bytes. So your captures should contain 9 bytes with the first byte always being zero. But they don't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are right. I just copied the Bytes of the actual number. The original Messages are much longer

Comment: When AMF says "network byte order", that means big-endian

Answer (score 0):

Likely your platform supports 8-byte IEEE-754 doubles but requires them to be in little-endian format. Your examples are in big-endian format. If you store them in an aligned array of unsigned characters from *last* to *first* and cast the pointer to a `double *`, you should get the right value.